# 32 vs 64 bit JRE under java9

Tags: java, windows-7, java-9

The new java 9 install images all appear to be 64 bit images.  Under Windows 7, I ended up with both 32 and 64 bit version of the JRE.  javaws by default is selecting the 64 bit version.  If I run the 32bit javaws directly from the command line, it works as well.

Previously the 32 and 64 bit installers were 2 different things.  How does the newly combined all in one approach decide what version to use?

Comment: Are you sure the 32-bit is Java 9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Release Note*** :- [Set 32 or 64 bit JRE requirements in a JNLP file](http://jdk.java.net/9/release-notes#JDK-8055448)

> Web Start applications can now specify requested JREs with their arch
>   attributes, and select the first one available that matches, even if
>   it is not the same arch (32 bit vs 64 bit) as the currently running
>   JRE. For example, the JNLP content below would place first preference
>   on 64 bit JDK8, and if not available, 32 bit JDK9:
>
> ```
> <resources arch="x86_64">
>      <java version="1.8"/>
> </resources>
> <resources arch="x86">
>     <java version="1.9"/>
> </resources>
> ```
>
> Note that in the above example, in order to launch a 64 bit 1.8 JRE, a
>   64 bit 9 JRE must be installed. If only a 32 bit 9 JRE is installed,
>   the 64 bit 1.8 JRE is unavailable.

Comment: This is the answer.  I marked as such and upvoted.  Thanks for pointing out what I should have found myself if I had read more carefully :).